# There is any Open source dating site?

Tags: open-source

I'm working on dating site project, but I can't find any open source dating site any more, please tell me,if any open source dating site. (PHP or ASP.NET)

Thanks,
Nguyen

Comment: does this mean that the people you date are open source developers? :)

Comment: Not programming related.

LMGTFY: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=php+dating+script

Comment: I was looking like you for a open source dating script. Tufat osDate is unfortunately outdated not maintained for years but I found https://github.com/pH7Software/pH7-Social-Dating-CMS which work well for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://www.tufat.com/s_free_dating_system.htm

Comment: any difference than tufat? thank GJ

Comment: Try http://friendnlove.sourceforge.net
There are few more open source dating code available at http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=dating

Answer (score 0):

I have tested osDate and it works, but takes a while to get running. I never attempted to have a go at the code so I can't say anything about it.
Today I would probably go for some CMS like Joomla and then add a dating plugin to it.